# Does PostgreSQL have a built-in feature to find United States federal holidays?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a built-in feature in PostgreSQL that would check if the date is a United States federal holiday? Such as return a boolean true if a date is/was a federal holiday.

Comment: Why would software with international reach specifically focus on American holidays?  You can find lists of such holidays online.

Comment: Federal holiday of which country during which regime?

Comment: @bereal I want for United States. Also corrected my question above.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wanted to check it via SQL itself.

Comment: Have you considered writing such a function yourself? It could even be driven by a table which could be kept up-to-date (and make it reasonably localizable).

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list from here:

```
create table public.federal_holidays (id int not null primary key, date date not null unique, description text);
copy public.federal_holidays from program 'curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shivaas/4758439/raw/b0d3ddec380af69930d0d67a9e0519c047047ff8/US%2520Bank%2520holidays'
with (format csv, header false);
```

Then query against it:

```
select exists (select 1 from public.federal_holidays where date = 'today') as today_is_a_public_holiday
```

Comment: Update your tables, or your holiday checker will stop working by the end of 2020.

Answer (score 1):

I am porting the python holidays package to PL/pgSQL. The United States function is completely converted.

It can be found [here](https://github.com/christopherthompson81/pgsql_holidays)

This will let you return a list of holidays for a state. A blank state would return the list of holidays that are not state-specific. Determining if a date is in the return would simply be a matter of doing

```
SELECT count(*) FROM holidays.usa('', 2020, 2020) h WHERE h.datestamp = my_date;
```