# Postgresql: how to add date and avoid weekend?

Tags: postgresql

i have following table `proses`

```
id title        created_at(Timestamp)    slaTime(Integer)
1  Proses One   2012-11-22 13:50:09.924  4
2  Proses Two   2012-11-22 13:50:09.924  6
```

I want to find the deadline with calculation deadline = created_at + slaTime(No. of days). **but** it also avoid a weekend.

for example on id 1, `2012-11-22` is monday so the deadline is `2012-11-26` (friday)
but on id 2, the deadline should be `2012-11-30` (tuesday) not `2012-11-28`(sunday)

Comment: Here's a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53677890/5298879). Avoiding weekeds in your question is the same as adding only business dates in the linked thread. Depending on the use case, you might want to also avoid holidays, which you'll have to [import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60015634/5298879).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add number of business days to given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677890/how-to-add-number-of-business-days-to-given-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXTRACT(DOW FROM timestamp)` in order to define the day of the week as Sunday(0) to Saturday(6), and then add some extra days depending on the resulting day of the week :

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN d.curr_date = 0
         THEN created_at + INTERVAL '1 day'
         WHEN d.curr_date = 6
         THEN created_at + INTERVAL '2 days'
         ELSE created_at 
       END
  FROM process
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM (created_at :: date + slaTime)) AS curr_date) AS d
```